# Redux-React: error in control flow while dispatchcing a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Please find my code below as I explain the flow that is currently happening:

First SampleParent calls fetchNames and when called, this populates reports array and returns a json array with 6 objects as of now.
Next, when I loop over the objects in reports array, each time 'fetchDownloadLink' function is called. The function executes till

```
fetch(uri, obj)
    .then(response => {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
            throw Error(response.status);
        }
        return response ;
    })
```

and instead of executing further returns back to SampleParent from where it was called for all 6 objects in the reports array.
Then it enters SampleChild and it renders onClick value as 'undefined'
Then finally the control suddendly seems to go back to 'fetchDownloadLink' function and executes the rest of the function to return the value of report_uri
and finally execution ends!

I dont understand why is this hapenning, I want the entire function to execute in one flow so that it would return the 'report_uri' value to 'onClick' prop of SampleChild

**store/index.js**

```
import C from '../constants'
import appReducer from '../reducers/reducers.js'
import thunkMiddleware  from 'redux-thunk'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
export default function configureStore() {
return createStore(
    appReducer,           
    applyMiddleware(
        thunkMiddleware))}
```

**Main_Root.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from '../store/index.js'
import SampleParent from './containers/SampleParent'
const store = configureStore()
export default class Root extends Component {
render() {return (<div><Provider store={store}><SampleParent /></Provider></div>)}}
```

**SampleParent.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchReport, fetchDownloadable } from '../../actions/actions'
import SampleChild from '../ui/SampleChild'
class SampleParent extends Component {
constructor(props) {super(props)}
componentDidMount() {this.props.fetchNames();}
render() {return (<div>
            <ul id="myUL">
                {this.props.reports.map((report) => (
                    <li><SampleChild
                            key={report.id}
                            label={report.label}
                            onClick={this.props.fetchDownloadLink("http://sample"+report.uri+".pdf")}
                        /></li>))}</ul></div>)}}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
const { reports } = state
return {reports}}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
return {fetchDownloadLink: url => dispatch(fetchDownloadable(url)),
    fetchNames: () => dispatch(fetchReport())}}
export default connect(mapStateToProps , mapDispatchToProps)(SampleParent)
```

**SampleChild.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
export default class SampleChild extends Component {
render() {const { key, label, onClick } = this.props
    return (<span className="inside_SampleChild" id={label}>
        {label}
        <a onClick={onClick}>Click me for pdf download!</img></a>
        </span>)}}
```

**fetchDownlodable function in action.js**

```
export const fetchDownloadable = (uri) => dispatch => {
var obj = {method: 'GET',
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ***=','Accept': 'application/json'},
    'credentials': 'include'};
fetch(uri, obj)
    .then(response => {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
            throw Error(response.status);}
        return response ;})
    .then((response) => response)
    .then(resourceLookup => {
        dispatch({
            type: C.FETCH_DOWNLOADABLE,
            report_uri: resourceLookup.url})
    }).
catch(error => {
    console.log("There was this  error" + error);});}
```

**reducer.js**

```
import C from '../constants'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
export const links = (state=null, action) => (action.type === C.FETCH_DOWNLOADABLE) ? action.report_uri : state
export const reports = (state=[], action) => {
switch(action.type) {
    case C.FETCH_REPORTS : return action.reports
    default : return state}}
const rootReducer = combineReducers({ reports, links})
export default rootReducer
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can see that you are invoking the function that you are passing to the child-component. Is that done on purpose?

Ex: {this.props.fetchDownloadLink("http://sample"+report.uri+".pdf")}

Comment: basically i just want a url to be passed to the child component 'SampleChild', so i thought of calling a function that would return a url string to the parameter 'onClick' and only the string will be passed to the child...

Answer (score 0):

When passing a function to a child to be used on onClick, invoking it will actually fire it right away, instead of giving it to the child as an onclick function.

Ex:

```
<ChildComponent onClick={somefunc} />
```

is fine

```
<ChildComponent onClick={somefunc("foo")} />
```

will fire the somefunc function and return the result of it to the child

If you meant to invoke this function on onClick, and bind it to something, you can do this:

```
<ChildComponent onClick={() => somefunc("foo")} />
```

This will pass it as a parameterless function to the child that can be triggered as this.props.onClick from the child

In your case, according to your comment, you are trying to send a string down to the child-component. A string cant be used as an onClick value, that has to be a function. If you use my last example above, that will send a function which again triggers somefunc, or in your example, the download.